# typescript readonly not a keyword

Tags: typescript

I copy pasted the example found on official typescript tutorial

```
class Octopus
{
    readonly name: string;
    readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8;
    constructor(theName: string)
    {
        this.name = theName;
    }
}
```

and this is throwing compile error at me. Compiler doesn't seem to recognize readonly as a keyword but rather thinks its a property. So it is complaining about "duplicate identifier 'readonly'".

Is there anything special I need to do to use readonly keyword? Visual studio 2015

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @ExplosionPills 1.7.4

Comment: readonly keyword is introcuded in 2.0. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#read-only-properties-and-index-signatures

Comment: TypeScript 1 is quite old. You probably want to work with 2.4 or 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readonly` is available from Typescript 2.0 onwards so you have to install Typescript 2.x SDK for visual studio to use it like below

in `type` definition :

```
type Foo = {
    readonly bar: number;
    readonly bas: number;
}
```

in function parameter  :

```
function foo(config: {
    readonly bar: number,
    readonly bas: number
}) {
    // ..
}
```

etc

Source : https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/10/31/typescript-2-0-read-only-properties